# How to use different API's with different Authentication headers in the same Angular JS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, api

Hello I'm just a AngularJs beginner and want some advice/help from u guys!

I am making an app where you can login and check your current location in the building through the Cisco CMX server. 
Its a server which calculates your position through the info of several access points you are connected with

I need to communicate with the mongodb for authenticating the users and I use a token for that.

And when I'm logged in I want to go to the API of the CMX with another authentication header.

But I cant see how it could work.

I set my default header in my app.js on run

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + $window.jwtToken;
```

And when I want to go to the CMX API i change my default header

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==';
```

But it wont do the trick..

Isn't it better to communicate with the CMX through the webserver itself instead of the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you want to intercept every HTTP request and inject it with an Authorization header containing a custom token.

to do that you need to use the angularjs **Interceptors**.

---

> The interceptors are service factories that are registered with the
>   $httpProvider by adding them to the $httpProvider.interceptors array.
>   The factory is called and injected with dependencies (if specified)
>   and returns the interceptor

---

Here is an example of an interceptor that injects a token if it’s available in browser’s local storage.

```
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function ($q, $location, $localStorage) {
   return {
       'request': function (config) {
           config.headers = config.headers || {};
           if ($localStorage.token) {
               config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
           }
           return config;
       },
       'responseError': function (response) {
           if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
               $location.path('/signin');
           }
           return $q.reject(response);
       }
   };
}]);
```

code inspired [from](https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)